# Group by day and count in measure in order to get Max, Min, Percentile etc. without an extra table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Good day. I am looking for a way to group the table below per day and count ID's using a measure, in order to be able to get max count, min count, percentile etc..

```
Date        ID
2018-01-01  ABC
2018-01-01  DEF
2018-01-01  GHI
2018-01-02  JKL
2018-01-02  MNO
2018-01-03  PQR
2018-01-03  STU
2018-01-03  VWX
```

I can create a table like that using:

```
group_by_count = SUMMARIZE(Table1;Table1[Date];"count";COUNTROWS(Table1)) 

Date    count
2018-01-01 00:00:00 3
2018-01-02 00:00:00 2
2018-01-03 00:00:00 3
```

However, I don't want an extra table in my report as my real data contains some years of data and other interesting columns I will filter on. Any ideas how to go about to do this, using only measures?

**Further clarification:**
My end goal is to get a measure that, for example, returns the max count. With my example data that would be 3. I will use this measure in cards and build dynamic texts for cards. Then I could build a text that says for example: "The maximum number of events in one day was 3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to actually create a new table. You can use the `SUMMARIZE` function within a measure. For example,

```
MaxCount = MAXX(SUMMARIZE(Table1; Table1[Date]; "Count"; COUNT(Table1[ID])); [Count])
```

Comment: I am not really following how a matrix visual would help me here? How could a matrix visual be used in a measure that, for example, returns max count?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a matrix. What visual are you using? What is your end goal?

Comment: My end goal is to get a measure that for example returns the max count. With my example data that would be 3. I will use this measure in cards and to build dynamic texts for cards. Then i could build a text that says for example: "The maximum number of events in one day was 3".

Comment: That's useful to know. I've edited that clarification into your question and will edit my answer to reflect your actual goal.